# Android : prevent edittext from hiding behind keyboard without changing manifest

Tags: android

Soft keyboard hides my edit text
this is my layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#F7F7F7"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:background="#C2C2C2"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/toggle1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:src="@drawable/img1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/toggle2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:src="@drawable/img2" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.65"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="#fff"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:visibility="gone" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/list1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.15"
        android:background="#EEEEEE"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/addCmntTextField"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:hint="Add a Comment"            
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="11dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:text="Save"
            android:clickable="true" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

in my menifest is wrote android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" and i cant change it otherwise it will efect my app.How can i do it please help.

This is my complete code

Comment: try this `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"`

Comment: Hi Tamilan,thanks for replying, i already tried it.It worked for this screen but creates problem for some other screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution that worked for me on samsung galaxy tab

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#F7F7F7"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="#C2C2C2"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/toggle1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="15dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/img1" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/toggle2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/img2" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:weightSum="1" >

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:background="#fff"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="vertical" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textColor="#000"
                            android:textSize="20sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:visibility="gone" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/list1"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:background="#EEEEEE"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:weightSum="1" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:weightSum="1" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/addCmntTextField"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:hint="Add a Comment"            
                android:text=""
                android:textSize="11dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="55dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:text="Save"
                android:clickable="true" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just implement a nesting in Layouts and this will solve the problem. Try doing this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="@color/white">

<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:weightSum="1">

        <EditText
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id=@+id/addCmntTextField"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="Add a Comment"/>

        <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Save"
                android:id="@+id/saveComment"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: KaHel, thanks for your reply.I tried your suggetion but it did'nt worked.

Comment: Sorry i did'nt posted my complete class, now i have posted the complete xml now see if you can help.Thanks

Comment: Hi @Agr1909, did you tested it on an actual device? Since your layout works just fine on my end using a Samsung Galaxy Tab.

Comment: Hi KaHel, i am also trying it on samsung galaxy tab 4.0.4. Did it worked for you with android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden".

Comment: @Agr1909 nope, I haven't added any special permission for this. try creating a test activity without those permissions just to make sure.

Comment: I also tested the same XML on LG Optimus G device. Works just fine.

Comment: Hi KaHel, yes it is working without special permissions,but i have to keep those permissions in my menifest to keep the previous screen working.Is there no way that it can work with that permission?

Comment: Hi @Agr1909, well I get it that you don't want to change the android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" but is it just because you don't want the Activity to show the softKeyboard when it gains focus? As for the comment above for stateHidden|adjustPan, If it works on your activity then just apply it to all of your activity in your AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: Hi, @KaHel, finally i got a solution of my problem.Instead of giving weight to all the layouts i gave fixed height to the layout that contain my edittext and button and it worked fine for me, even with all the special permissions, but anyways thanks for your help :)